# editor with plugins in ruby?

Tags: ruby, plugins, editor

I'm looking for extensible linux editor(GUI) that may be extended with plugins written in ruby. Editor shouldn't be written in java or ruby.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

vim has a ruby api. you could try [here](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/1027) for starters.

Comment: i'm using vim. i don't like it :(

Comment: To expand on Peter's comment:

Do a "vim --version | grep ruby" from the command-line and look for +ruby. If you see it you have the ability to run Ruby scripts inside vim. From inside vim type ":h ruby" for more info.

If you don't see +ruby then Ruby support was not compiled in. At that point you can either use your *nix distribution package manager and install the full version of Vim, or compile it from source. I usually go for the source version because the packages are usually pretty stale, but your mileage might vary.

Comment: once again: i don't like vim!

Answer (score 0):

Not to be Mr. Obvious, but, um, how about Emacs?

http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+emacs

You might find some help in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120/which-text-code-editor-on-linux-is-most-similar-to-textmate) as well.

Comment: What i want is to be able to extend editor with ruby. Emacs is using elisp as it's internal language and there is absolutely no way to use ruby for writing extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Allegedly, jed does this, I think -- although I was put off by the fact that it's a curses-based editor.